# Using boot on subset of data

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

From the [boot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf) documentation, it looks like it should be possible to pass information about which observations to use for bootstrapping directly via the command, but I cannot figure out how to access the indices.

To take a simple example, say I want to use only cars with automatic transmissions for my bootstrap. One way would be to subset the data directly.

```
# Bootstrap on a subset of mtcars
library(boot)
my_func <- function(data, i) {
  d <- data[i,]
  m <- lm(mpg ~ disp + log(hp), data = d)
  beta <- m$coefficients['log(hp)']
  y_mean <- mean(m$model[, 1])
  # Return estimated elasticity
  return(beta / y_mean)
}
my_boot <- boot(mtcars[mtcars$am == 1, ], my_func, R = 100)
```

My question is whether it is possible to achieve the same effect using the options in boot(). In this simple case, it might not make much sense, but imagine a much more complicated set of conditions passed from a list.

Comment: Check out argument `strata`. And try `boot(mtcars, etc, strata = mtcars$am)`.

Comment: Thanks, but that produces the same statistics as using the full sample rather than the restricted sample. The same happens if I use `strata = mtcars$am == 1`.

Comment: If you `set.seed` prior to running `boot` and then set the same seed and run `boot(..., strata = mtcars$am)` the values of `mean(my_boot$t)` and of `mean(my_boot_2$t)` are different.